Two-way binding in WPF - where a cache-object is within another bound object
I cannot get a two-way binding in WPF to work as it should do.
What I got is a class called UserCache having a property called 'Current'. An Object of this class is placed within a facading class, called ConnectedUserCache, which also has got a property, called 'Current'.
MainWindow.xaml
[...]
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ConnectedUserCache/>
</Window.DataContext>
[...]
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Style="{StaticResource style1}" >Vorname:</Label>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Current.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />  
    <Label Style="{StaticResource style1}" Grid.Row="1">Nachname:</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Current.LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Label Style="{StaticResource style1}" Grid.Row="2">Telefon:</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=Current.PhoneNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
[...]
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UsersShown}" Margin="0,30,0,-280" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                 IsReadOnly="True"
                 Name="UserDataGrid"
                 SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                 AutoGeneratingColumn="UserDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
                 SelectedCellsChanged="UserDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged"/>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       private ConnectedUserCache _cache = new ConnectedUserCache();

       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           DataContext = _cache;

            // Otherwise DataGrid would not be filled at the beginning
            _cache.RefreshAsync();
            ReloadDataGrid(_cache);
       }

        private void ReloadDataGrid(ConnectedUserCache? cache)
        {
            UserDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
            UserDataGrid.ItemsSource = cache.UsersShown;
        }

       private void Button_SeachUserInCache_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
          var cache = DataContext as ConnectedUserCache;
          if (cache == null) return; 

          cache.SearchCurrentUser();

          // Reload datasource of datagrid
         UserDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
         UserDataGrid.ItemsSource = cache.UsersShown;
      }
[...]


ConnectedUserCache.cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using UserWpfClient.Http;
using UserWpfClient.LocalData;

namespace UserWpfClient
{
    internal class ConnectedUserCache : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private UserCache _userCache = new UserCache();
        private HttpUserClient _userClient = new HttpUserClient();

        public ConnectedUserCache() {}
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
[...]

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public UserModelView Current
        {
           get { return _userCache.Current; }
           set 
           { 
              _userCache.Current = value; 
              OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Current));
           }
        }
[...]

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
[...]


UserCache.cs
public class UserCache : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Collection<UserModelView> _allUsers = new Collection<UserModelView>();
    private UserModelView _current =  new UserModelView();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<UserModelView> UsersShown { get; set; } = [];

    public UserModelView Current 
    { 
        get => _current; 
        set
        {
            _current = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Current));
        } 
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private bool GetSomeUsersByFirstName()
    {
        var result = new List<UserModelView>();
        foreach (var item in _allUsers)
        {
            if (item.FirstName == Current.FirstName) result.Add(item);
        }
        UsersShown = new ObservableCollection<UserModelView>(result);

        // Feedback to the user, for what we have been looking for
        Current = new UserModelView()
        { 
            FirstName = Current.FirstName,
            LastName = string.Empty, 
            PhoneNumber = string.Empty
        };

        return UsersShown.Any();
    }

    public bool Refresh()
    {
       UsersShown = new ObservableCollection<UserModelView>(_allUsers);
       Current = new UserModelView();
       return UsersShown.Any();
    }

[...]

UserViewModel.cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using UserWpfClient.Attributes;

namespace UserWpfClient.LocalData
{
    public class UserModelView : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _firstName = string.Empty;
        private string _lastName = string.Empty;
        private string _phoneNumber = string.Empty;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        [ColumnName("Vorname")]
        public string FirstName
        {
            get => _firstName ?? string.Empty;

            set
            {
                _firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FirstName));
            }
        }

        [ColumnName("Nachname")]
        public string LastName 
        { 
            get => _lastName ?? string.Empty; 
            set 
            { 
                _lastName = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LastName));
            }
        }

        [ColumnName("Telefon")]
        public string PhoneNumber 
        { 
            get => _phoneNumber ?? string.Empty; 
            set
            {
                _phoneNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PhoneNumber));
            } 
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

I found the following: Two-way binding in WPF
and Wpf two way binding in listbox .
And as you can see, I changed there classes (UserCache,  ConnectedUserCache and UserModelView) acordingly.
At next I will follow this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty  But as it reduces the amount of boilerplate, I think I still have to understand the root cause of my problem, which means understanding WPF and its Events much better.
MainWindow.xaml
There I made several attempts with Mode=TwoWay and/or UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.
UserCache.cs
There I tried it with and without INotifyPropertyChanged.
Expectation and what really happens:
I expect that if those TextBoxes have got content, that related property 'Current' has also got such content, as also property 'Current' within - and all this the other way arround, too.
But what happens is, if I write something into one of those textboxes during runtime as a user, to e.g. start filtering users on a datagrid (bound to the cache behind), it works fine. Then, after showing all users again (which works fine) and input the textbox is still be shown, when I  start filtering again, it should work like before - as it uses the same code.
But it doesn't filter again. I have to rewrite into the textbox again. So it seems like the bounding needs an update-trigger or in other words boudning seems to be lost for this specific moment.
Questions:
So, when I write down these lines, I wonder if I search in the wrong direction. Is this a binding-problem?  Or does the problem lie somewhere else? Which classes should be of INotifyChanged in my example?
My next step:
If you give me a fiew moments, during the next days, I will my git-repositiories (WPF-Client and Backend-Sercice) make public. But, please don't expect something operfect. It is just a study for learning.

Hey Nick, it would help us if you show how your filtering method looks like and removed/cleaned unnecessary comments and code (I already did some editing, but the nesting doesn't fit/you probably didn't write down some class definition?). Also the definition (how is binded) UserDataGrid is missing from xaml.

Binding of 'UserDataGrid' does work well. I have got no problem there. I only got an problem with properties 'Current'. That's the reason why I did not show definition of 'UserDataGrid'.

I suppose filtering method isn't the reason for the problem as well, because at the beginning of push-button-method (which is shown) in local variable 'cache' content of property 'Current' can be missing as described, whereas content of property 'UsersShown' is always available as expected.

I added now one of those filtering methods as an example.  A switch lets decide which of those filtering methods will be used.  All filtering methods nearly look the same.

If you're expecting OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Current)) to have an effect ... it doesn't. "Current" isn't a "property" in the binding sense (like "LastName") . I'm also not sure if your .DataContext is in sync with your "cache" / "current" (possible) changes.

Added bound DataGrid as you wished, Tatranskymedved.

Thank you, Gerry.  So which knowledge do I miss?  How can I bind both, Current and UsersShown,  especially as compiler tells me that only one can be mentioned as Window.DataContex and especially as I have to mention a class but not an object?

For example: Does each layer of code require a own XAML file, so each can be mentioned within Window.DataContext?

Or:  Should I always bind ModelView-classes, only?  (Which I would find obvious.) But then, how should I treat UsersShown?

This is the only thing that makes sense in your scenario:  _current = value; _current.OnPropertyChanged(""); This cascades the bindings when you change a .DataContext. You need to reference the "PropertyChanged" handler on the correct data object. Every control can have their own DataContext; which each child then inherits; which adds to the confusion if one doesn't keep this inheritance hierarchy in mind. MVVM introduces a lot of "indirection" which adds to the confusion. I would suggest prototyping any bindings the "old" way; when that works, you can obfusticate it with MVVM.


Is this a binding-problem?

Yes, it is. Because, bound property Current won't be updated.

Or does the problem lie somewhere else?

Yes, it does in some way.

If you expect problems in the code somewhere else, why not unit-testing such areas of code.
The root-cause of this problem lies in the misunderstanding of the MVVM concept. Understood right, piece of code can be reasonable tested.


Which classes should be of INotifyChanged in my example?

I think, here DataContext should be considered, too. ICommand or one of its substitutes like RelaisCommand/DelegateCommand could be also taken into account.
For direct answer to this question see below.
Root-cause:
Given code of question can be understood as layers like this:

Class ConnectedUserCache works as view-model, as it is bound to the view. But also it adds http-connection to an underlying class, called UserCache.
Class UserCache contains business logic, which should be placed in view-model.

But it should be like this:

Business logic, between property Current (or its properties) and UsersShown should be placed on the same layer, working as view-model, both bound to the view (MainWindow). So for both DataContext will be the same, the view-model.
http-connection to the database as well as some kind of cache should be placed below.

INotifyChanged:
If layers are placed as they should be (as decribed above), then class defining model-view will be of INotifyChanged, if properties FirstName, LastName and PhoneNumber will be placed there directly. If property UsersShown of type ObservableCollection will be placed there and used with its methods right there, another INotifyChanged won't be necessary. Class UserViewModel (as named in the question) will need to be of INotifyChanged, if its propterties are not used directly on model-view.
